# Subprocess module has no attribute STARTUPINFO

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a small network scanner to play around with.

Code:

```
# Configure subprocess to hide the console window

info = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()

info.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW

info.wShowWindow = subprocess.SW_HIDE
```

This is the block causing problems. At runtime I get the following error:

```
Enter a network address in CIDR format(ex.192.168.1.0/24): 192.168.1.1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scannerMock.py", line 17, in <module>
    info = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
AttributeError: module 'subprocess' has no attribute 'STARTUPINFO'
```

I've looked around online and have reinstalled the subprocess module to no avail, any idea why it's doing this?

Full code:

```
# Import modules
import subprocess
import ipaddress
import os
import sys
# Prompt the user to input a network address
net_addr = input("Enter a network address in CIDR format(ex.192.168.1.0/24): ")

# Create the network
ip_net = ipaddress.ip_network(net_addr)

# Get all hosts on that network
all_hosts = list(ip_net.hosts())

# Configure subprocess to hide the console window
#startupinfo = None
info = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
info.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
info.wShowWindow = subprocess.SW_HIDE

# For each IP address in the subnet,
# run the ping command with subprocess.popen interface
for i in range(len(all_hosts)):
    output = subprocess.Popen(['ping', '-c', '1', '-w', '500', str(all_hosts[i])], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, startupinfo=info).communicate()[0]

    if "Destination host unreachable" in output.decode('utf-8'):
        print(str(all_hosts[i]), "is Offline")
    elif "Request timed out" in output.decode('utf-8'):
        print(str(all_hosts[i]), "is Offline")
    else:
        print(str(all_hosts[i]), "is Online")
```

Comment: Did you get this to work? I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Linux by any chance? I've encountered the same issue under Ubuntu. I discovered that the Python 3 docs say STARTUPINFO class is only available under Windows. See [subprocess.STARTUPINFO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.STARTUPINFO).

Comment: The error message in the comment to the older answer looks like MacOS. The gist of this answer is still correct.

Comment: So then what's the alternative for us Linux users?

Comment: @Rylan - Since STARTUPINFO is a Windows construct, it's meaningless to Linux and so not required. You can simply omit this argument to the Popen call as the default is None. The python 3.7.4 docs recommend using the run method instead of Popen, where possible. That would avoid the issue altogether.

Answer (score 0):

You've likely clobbered `subprocess` somehow. Do `print subprocess.__ file__` and I'd bet it's not from the core.

Comment: It is from the core. I got - /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py 
and getting the same error- AttributeError: module 'subprocess' has no attribute 'STARTUPINFO'

Comment: Where did you run the check? Inside the file you showed above?

Comment: And do you have a file or folder called subprocess in the same directory as the script?